# Zeros of Vandermonde-like matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I met this question in the proof of Hausdorff property of Grassmann manifold. For two real vector $x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n),y=(y_1,\cdots,y_n) \in \mathbb{R}^k,$ consider the following function
$$
f(x,y)=\sum_{l=1}^k\sum_{1\leq i_1< \cdots <i_{k+1}\leq n}(\det \begin{pmatrix}
 x_1^{i_1}& \cdots & x_1^{i_{k+1}} \\
 \vdots & & \vdots \\
 x_k^{i_1}& \cdots & x_k^{i_{k+1}} \\
 y_l^{i_1} &\cdots & y_l^{i_{k+1}}
\end{pmatrix})^2.
$$
If $f(x,y)=0,$ how can I prove that there is a invertible matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}$ so that $x=Ay$?

Comment: Are $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{R}^k$?